# Global Descriptor Table and Local Descriptor Table

Tags: windows, operating-system, x86, intel

I want to know if the global descriptor table resides in each process memory space or it is shared among all processes.
What about LDT?
Where is the LDTR stored?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.internals.com/articles/protmode/protmode.htm

There is a book called 'The Indespensible PC Hardware Book' by Hans-Peter Messmer that goes into this in some detail.

Comment: The link is dead. It would also be helpful if you included a short answer to answer the question.